# Check Payment Status in gform_after_submition GravityForm

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

we use custom payment plugin on GravityForm for payment.

and we write a function on FORM ID 4 :

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission_4', 'landing_simulator', 10, 2 );
function landing_simulator($entry, $form) {
  $first_name = rgar( $entry, '1' );
  $last_name = rgar( $entry, '3' );
 
  // SEND a SMS or run Script.
}
```

now , how can we check payment status and when Status is Completed, run a script?